# how to define functions with a referenced parameter in metal shader language except for vertex, fragment and kernel functions

Tags: metal

When porting some basic OpenGL ES 2.0 shader to Metal shader, I don't know how to convert the in/inout/out qualifier in glsl to metal shader language(MSL). For example,

```
//OpenGL vertex shader

...

void getPositionAndNormal(out vec4 position, out vec3 normal, out vec3 tangent, out vec3 binormal)
{
    position = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    normal = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    tangent = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    binormal = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}

void main()

{
    ...

    vec4 position;
    vec3 normal;
    vec3 tangent;
    vec3 binormal;
    getPositionAndNormal(position, normal, tangent, binormal);

    ...
}
```

when attempting convert to MSL, I try to use reference in the getPositionAndNormal  parameters:

```
void getPositionAndNormal(float4 & position, float3 & normal, float3 & tangent, float3 & binormal);
```

I get the following compile error information: `reference type must have explicit address space qualifier`

According to section 4.2 in [Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf), I use device address space to reference the getPositionAndNormal parameters in the following forms:

```
void getPositionAndNormal(device float4 & position, device float3 & normal, device float3 & tangent, device float3 & binormal);
```

This time, the error message I got was no matching function for call to 'getPositionAndNormal'.

```
void getPositionAndNormal (
  device float4 & position,
  device float3 & normal,
  device float3 & tangent,
  device float3 & binormal)
{
  position = float4(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  normal = float3(1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  tangent = float3(1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  binormal = float3(1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}

vertex ShaderOutput vertexShader (ShaderInput inputMTL [[stage_in]], constant ShaderUniform& uniformMTL [[buffer(1)]])
{
  ...

  float3 binormal = 0;
  float3 tangent = 0;
  float3 normal = 0;
  float4 position = 0;
  getPositionAndNormal (position, normal, tangent, binormal);

  ...
}
```

What's the right 'metal' way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The local variables in `vertexShader()` are in the `thread` address space, not the `device` address space. Therefore, you should declare the parameters of `getPositionAndNormal()` to be of `thread` address space, too.

The `device` address space are for things shared across the device; that is, across all "threads" or invocations of your shader. These variables are specific to each thread/invocation. They're not shared.

I suspect the full "no matching function" compiler error would have explained the mismatch between the declared parameter and the actual passed argument, although possibly somewhat cryptically.